# How to disable auto backspace in Excel VBA editor

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

When typing in the editor it puts me back on the end of the last word.

For example, I want `Sub Entername()`

If I'm not typing quickly enough it goes: `SubEnterName()`.

How do I turn this off.

Answer (score 8):

I've heard of this problem before. Try these steps:

1. Close down excel.
2. Open it first it in safe mode (type "excel.exe /s" in the run box).
3. Open the VBA Editor and attempt to write a macro. The issue *should* not occur
4. Close down excel and re open it normally

I've heard these steps have fixed this issue before for others.

Comment: I have heard the same thing! You can also get into safe mode by holding 'CTRL' while starting Excel (at least in 2010).

Comment: Oh yeah! Ctrl+click. Forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any VBE addins like Smart Indenter or Code Cleaner? Remove Code Cleaner and install it only when you are going to use it, then uninstall it when you are done. I had the same problem and Code Cleaner was the culprit. I believe it might be the two of them together that causes it.

For reference:

- [VBA Code Cleaner](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm)
- [Smart Indenter](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/indentpage.asp)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because of a COM Add-In called 'Load Test Report Addin'. to disable it, do the following:
go to `Excel Options` -> `Add-Ins` and choose `Excel COM Add-ins` from bottom drop down and press `Go...` button. then uncheck the 'Load Test Report Addin' item to diable it. this will clear the problem!

Answer (score 1):

To prevent auto refreshing and deleting back-spaces in VBA editor, you should make sure that all forms or reports that have On-Timer Event Procedures are in design view or the code should be turned-off (i.e. converted into comments).

However, it is better to make sure that all forms and reports are in design view which means none of the On-Timer codes are executing.

I hope this helps.

Shafiu.

Comment: This solved my problem in Access VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have AutoSave turned on?  I had a file doing this just now.  While typing, as SOON as I stopped, AutoSave was working away - (inadvertently, I'm sure) this was causing VBE to kill spaces.

Did two tests:
-Moved the file off Sharepoint onto my local machine, worked fine
-Turned off AutoSave on the Sharepoint copy, worked fine

Comment: Are you seriously *asking* someone who posted this back in 2011??

Comment: This post still comes up in Google searches, so yes.  I had the issue EXACTLY as described.  It's a direct solution that hasn't been brought up yet, not broad Excel troubleshooting. I solved my problem and put my solution out there for others, which I thought was the point of stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Mac. after searching on the internet I found out it's a bug, and you need to do these to get rid of it:
1- Turn off auto-save
2- Disable the automatic calculator

It's not an optimal solution, but it no longer annoys you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The reason was a Microsoft Web Browser element in a spreadsheet that constantly updated a URL. After removing it, everything went back to normal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).